# NetBeans C++ V8 lib namespace

Tags: c++, netbeans, namespaces, v8

I am trying to embed javascript to a somewhat big C++ tool, and I am using NetBeans. I started trying to run the hello_world example, and it does compile and run perfectly through command line compilaton, using this:

```
g++ -I$HOME/v8/ -L$HOME/v8/ hello_world.cpp -o hello_world -Wl,--start-group ~/v8/out/native/obj.target/{tools/gyp/libv8_{base,libbase,snapshot,libplatform},third_party/icu/libicu{uc,i18n,data}}.a -Wl,--end-group -ldl -lrt -pthread -std=c++11
```

However, trying to link the libs through the NetBeans option on the linker and adding the other compilation flags to the compiler, it doesn't compile.

Moreover, NetBeans finds hundreds upon hundreds of errors in v8.h regarding Namespace. For instance:

```
/home/andreoliv/v8/include/v8.h:4567:13: error: ‘Handle’ has not been declared
```

Which makes reference to:

```
  int match(Handle<Value> value);
```

And is inside the v8.h file, where Handle and Value are declared. 
Modifying the 4567th line to:

```
int match(v8::Handle<v8::Value> value);
```

Gets rid of the error, which makes me believe this problem is strongly connected with the way NetBeans deals with the namespace.

The problematic types, such as Value and Handle, are declared within the v8 namespace, and yet the compiler is complaining about the namespace not being specified.

It would be nearly impossible to waste time changing all the names to v8::. Is there any other option or setting that I overlooked, and could be used in this case?